# How to prevent reflection to access a class or method in java

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-library, aar

I have developed an android library and I want to prevent reflection to access my class fields and methods. I remember something about `SecurityManager` but I don't know if it can help.

How can I achieve such functionality ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to control by preventing reflection? If the problem is security, are the standard Android app-isolation mechanisms not sufficient?

Comment: This is a library containg an AIDL service, which will be ultimately used by a third-party app. I want to make sure the third-party app does not make any malicious changes to my classes and variables at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM has security mechanisms that allows you to define restrictions to code through a Java security policy file.
It will use the default one unless you specify otherwise.

Run your application using a SecurityManager and a sufficiently restrictive security policy, policy can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

You may find this tutorial useful:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html